# Cucumber: Undefined step although the step is defined(Ruby)

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

I  am trying to make a simple test case with feature file scenario:

```
Feature: Amazon Search Functionality

Scenario: Users can search for a specific item on Amazon
    Given a user goes to Amazon
    When they search for "pens"
    Then amazon should return results for "pens"
```

Ruby code for step definition is:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'cucumber'

Given(/^a user goes to Amazon$/) do
  @browser= Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
  @browser.goto "http://www.amazon.com"
end

When(/^they search for "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg|
  @browser.text_field(:id=> "twotabsearchtextbox").set "#{arg}"
  @browser.send_keys: return
end

Then(/^amazon should return results for "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg|
  @browser.div(:id=>"result_2").wait_untill_present
  page_output = @browser.div(:id=> "resultsCol").text.include? "#{arg}"
  assert (page_output=true)
  @browser.close

end
```

I am getting output:
Testing started at 3:49 AM

```
C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\ruby.exe -EUTF-8 C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\cucumber C:/Users/rahulpathak01/Desktop/automatedtest/Features/Amazon_search.feature --format Teamcity::Cucumber::Formatter --expand --color -r features
WARNING: The formatter Teamcity::Cucumber::Formatter is using the deprecated formatter API which will be removed in v4.0 of Cucumber.

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given("a user goes to Amazon") do
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end


You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

When("they search for {string}") do |string|
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end


You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Then("amazon should return results for {string}") do |string|
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end
1 scenario (1 undefined)
3 steps (3 undefined)
0m0.019s
```

My folder structure is correct still rubymine is unable to find step definitions.

Folder structure:

```
Features
   Step Definitions
        test.rb
   testfeatures.feature
```

Comment: FWIW: you should use `watir` instead of `watir-webdriver`.

Comment: *"My folder structure is correct"* -- Can you please clarify, what *is* your folder structure? This would be my first guess at the cause of the problem.

Comment: @TomLord edited the question with folder structure at the last.

Comment: @RahulPathak I would expect the folder name to be `step_definitions`, not `Step Definitions`. I'm not certain whether it will still work with a capital letter, or a space. (I'm also not on a Windows machine, so it's not easy for me to verify if that works, in your environment.)

Comment: Also as a matter of convention, but (I think) not a requirement, I would usually *expect* step files in `step_definitions/` to be called `<something>_steps.rb`. But I don't think the `_steps` postfix is strictly necessary.

Comment: I also have this question, answer would be appreciated!!!!!